# Can I check syntax only with Visual Studio Command Prompt?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, command-prompt

I'm trying to check the syntax of a c file using the visual command prompt, im using the cl command but it's generating two files, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what output does it give? because im only getting the name of the file.

Comment: _When using this option, no output files are created, and error messages are written to standard output._ when it  has error, messages output to standart output.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we9a1ahs(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It's not giving me any error messages though, im doing cl /Zs filename.c

Comment: Is it contains the syntax error in the filename.c?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I got it to work but it doesn't seem to check the functions syntax,                                                                                                    im using this code and its not giving me the error:                                    #include <stdio.h>
 
ma()
{
    pntf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}

Comment: It is correct as syntax. (c89)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY [Code](http://paste.ofcode.org/WP6GaJHS9DNBuk4S4eP2rF)

Comment: Resolve of function names is done by the linker.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So I guess it's not possible to do this, because the linker needs the .obj file ,right?

Comment: It does not need at the time of parsing. That is, at the time of the link will result in an error, but it is not at the time of parsing.